# How to configure custom access-log format for Glassfish-4.1 (worked in v3.1.2.2, ignored in v4.1)

Tags: glassfish

I am converting some in-house systems from Glassfish-3.1.2.2 (on Java 1.7) to Glassfish-4.1 (on Java 1.8).  We need a custom access log format to capture some data not present in the default log format specifier.

Glassfish-4.1 seems to be ignoring the format specifier (and for that matter, all other custom settings) in the "access-log" element in the domain.xml file.  These config options worked flawlessly in Glassfish-3.1.2.2.

Specifically, consider the following from a working Glassfish-3.1.2.2 system, in the "..../configs/domain.xml" file.  Certain values have been redacted, but the actual text is not relevant.

```
<configs>
  <config name="server-config">
    <http-service access-logging-enabled="true">
      <access-log buffer-size-bytes="128000" write-interval-seconds="1" format="'%client.name% %datetime% %request% %status% %response.length% %session.com.redacted.redacted.User% %header.user-agent% %header.X-REDACTED%'"></access-log>
```

This works great in Glassfish-3.1.2.2.  However, in Glassfish-4.1, the settings (format and write-interval-seconds) seem to be ignored (not sure how to test 'buffer-size-bytes').

I can see the custom access-log format string in the Glassfish-4.1 admin console: (https://host:4848/) -> Configurations -> server-config -> HTTP Service -> Access Logging -> Format.

I performed a few experiments (all failed).

1. I placed the format string into the "default-config" as well.  This is contrary to the documentation (for GF-3, the "default-config" is used as a template to create new configs for new domains, and it NOT used by any running domain).  As expected, this edit had no effect on the actual access log file (post service restart).
2. I edited the log format string from the admin web interface.  I appended the static string "ABC123TEST", saved the config and restarted the server.  Sure enough, the literal text "ABC123TEST" appears in the correct location in domain.xml, but it totally ignored when the access logfile is written out.

Example of incorrect access log file (some data edited for secrecy):

`"1.2.3.4" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "09/Jun/2015:10:59:10 -0600" "GET /logoff-action.do HTTP/1.1" 200 0`

Correct/desired access log sample:

`"1.2.3.4" "09/Jun/2015:11:00:01 -0600" "GET /logoff-action.do;jsessionid=0000000000000000000000000000 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "REDACTED-USER-NAME" "AwesomeUserAgentStr/1.0" "REDACTED-X-HEADER-VALUE"`

Comment: I found this document. Perhaps it will help? "Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v3 Domain File Format Reference" [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17811_01/html/820-7694/abhay.html#abhaz](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17811_01/html/820-7694/abhay.html#abhaz)